NetworkManager slow boot in Ubuntu 24.04
Currently, on my laptop I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 which I installed a few days ago, and it takes a long time to boot up. Using the systemd-analyze blame command, I noticed that it's NetworkManager.service's fault. Following the advice from this question (Help me troubleshoot slow boot since 24.04 upgrade), I tried forgetting all Wi-Fi networks, and the boot time decreased dramatically. I specify that I am using a Wi-Fi connection, not Ethernet. At this point I wanted to ask if there is anyone who has found a solution that does not involve forgetting all Wi-Fi networks at each reboot.

The boot process only waits for the network to be active if there is something that declares a dependency on it -- on a normal system no services do that, so the network configures in the background.
Forgetting all networks makes network configuration fail, which also allows booting to progress, but the actual problem is that something is waiting for the network to be configured, and wifi takes a while (because it requires a network scan (which has a 2 second timeout) and a DHCP lease (which typically has a five second collision detection period).

So if I disable the service that uses the network manager, the boot time should decrease?

There are a myriad of reasons for slow boot times. It really can be frustrating. I'm using 'legacy' boot om my Dell 1545 and this fixed my slow boot issue. It may or may not work for you.
In /etc/default/grub edit the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" entry:
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
Edit:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="tsc=unstable"
Save the file, then
sudo update-grub
Reboot.
From: [SOLVED] Slow Boottime on Legacy Laptop
(Not sure if I'm allowed to post links here or not).
